# Transform from WGS84 to Cylindrical Equal Area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

What transformation should I use to go from GCS_WGS_1984 to Sphere_Cylindrical_Equal_Area?

I am using Arc to project a dataset over for and area calculation and then will project it back.

Comment: I was able to answer this using arcpy.CreateCustomGeoTransformation_management converted to Python from ArcMap, as is seen here:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/48932

Comment: Hi @Mathew, you can answer your own question below and mark it as the accepted answer, so future readers will easily be able to find both your problem and its solution.

Answer (score 1):

The question's [asker reported](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/transform-from-wgs84-to-cylindrical-equal-area#comment172269_120946) that he

> was able to answer this using
>   [arcpy.CreateCustomGeoTransformation_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000076000000) converted to Python
>   from ArcMap

He followed advice in a [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/48932).